# Webpack doesn't load images from given path in ng-src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, webpack

I am trying to show a different image for every item in in the ng-repeat.
I first encountered some problems with webpack loading the images and understanding the attributes in the HTML. I could resolve those issues by changing the html loader from:

```
 {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw'
 },
```

to:

```
 {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loaders: [
                "html?" + JSON.stringify({
                    attrs: ["img:src", "img:ng-src"]
                })
            ]
        },
```

and by adding the two following loaders to load the images:

```
{ test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
{ test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" }
```

Now whenever I use a path directly to an image, the image is loaded like it should be:

```
<img ng-src = "../images/lupine.png"/>
```

However, when I try to load the images for every item in the ng-repeat:

```
 <div class="menuItem__taskForm menuItem__checkboxes">
            <label ng-repeat="allergeen in allergenen" class="menuItem__checkbox">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="selectedAllergenen[]"
            value="allergeen"
            ng-model="allergeen.selected"
            >
            <img ng-src = "{{'../images/' + allergeen.naam + '.png'}}"/>
        </label>
   </div>
```

I get to see broken images on the webpage, even though when I inspect element in the browser I can see that the URI to the image has been concatenated correctly:

result from inspecting one of the broken images in the browser:

```
<img ng-src="../images/lupine.png" src="../images/lupine.png">==$0
```

At first this question might seem straight forward and easy to be found on the internet, but I have searched for quite some time now and I still haven't been able to fix this problem.

I hope you guys can give me new insights on how to properly fix this.

Comment: Looks like your HTML is getting rendered before JS replace ng-src

Comment: Is there any way to change the render order you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the following code to my controller:

```
$scope.loadImage = function(image) {
return require('../img/allergenen/' + image + '.png');
};
```

I then call this in the HTML like this:

```
 <img src="{{loadImage(allergeen.naam)}}" />
```

By doing this webpack immediately started resolving the png files,
so I guess the problem was that I wasn't requiring the needed resources and 
webpack didn't know that he had to resolve those for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize img src only after `allergeen.naam` is available and the correct syntax is

```
<img ng-src = "../images/{{allergeen.naam}}.png" ng-if="allergeen.naam"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think there might be something wrong with my Webpack because now I'm getting an error saying Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ..images/{{allergeen.naam}}.png in the Html page.

Comment: @DennisNoens This might help https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981